How can I get data from binary file?
I get 'binary file' made with write() member function.
'binary file' have 2'000'000 of Player.
class Player {
    string name;            // name, length[3, 15]
    int score;              // score
    size_t id;              // id, There may be overlapping IDs.
    size_t num;             // Number of bytes secured in free store
    unique_ptr<char[]> p;   // Memory secured in free store (saved characters)


write() is a member of class Player.
void write(ostream& os) {
    os.write((char*)this, sizeof(Player));
    os.write((char*)p.get(), num);
}

I try to save these all Player data in container.
void read(istream& is) {
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(Player));
    p = make_unique<char[]>(num);
    is.read(p.get(), num);
}

But the program return aborb() error.
There's my whole code.
int main()
{
    ifstream in{ "player files", ios::binary };
    if (not in) { return 0; }

    vector<Player> players;
    
    while (in.peek() != EOF) {
        Player temp;
        temp.read(in);
        players.push_back(temp);
    }

    Player& lastPlayer = players.back();
    cout << "name: " << lastPlayer.getName() << ", id: " << lastPlayer.getId() << ", score: "
        << lastPlayer.getScore() << ", num: " << lastPlayer.getNum() << endl;
    cout << "string: " << lastPlayer.getP() << endl;
}

Q1. Is there any problem with my copy assigment operator?
public:
    Player() {}
    ~Player() {}

    Player(const Player& other)
        : name(other.name), score(other.score), id(other.id), num(other.num)
    {
        p = make_unique<char[]>(num);
        memcpy(p.get(), other.p.get(), num);
    }

    Player& operator=(const Player& rhs)
    {
        if (this == &rhs)
            return *this;

        p.reset(rhs.p.get());

        return *this;
    }

    Player(Player&& other) noexcept
        : name(move(other.name)), score(other.score), id(other.id), num(other.num)
    {
        p = move(other.p);
        other.num = 0;
    }
    Player& operator=(Player&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        if (this == &rhs)
            return *this;

        name = move(rhs.name);
        score = rhs.score;
        id = rhs.id;
        num = rhs.num;

        p = move(rhs.p);
        rhs.num = 0;

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const Player& rhs) const
    {
        if (num != rhs.num)
            return false;

        return equal(p.get(), p.get() + num, rhs.p.get());
    }

    void read(istream& is) {
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(Player));
        p = make_unique<char[]>(num);
        is.read(p.get(), num);
    }

        // getter
};

Q2. How can i save Player data in vector(or any container) as well?
I hope to be able to store Player data in a container and sort&searching it smoothly.

std::string cannot be serialised by just dumping bytes into a file. Most implementations are just 3-4 pointers and nothing else.

And, more importantly, while you can certainly write a std::string into the file like that to produce some garbage data in the file, reading that garbage into an std::string will definitely cause problems... Same applies to the unique_ptr. If the lengths given in the comment are correct, you could just make it char[16] and maybe get around making a proper serialization/deserialization...

Consider using SQLite as your binary file format.  In the meantime for development purposes, use a text file as the file format to serialize write-to and deserialize read-from.

Please do not delete and re-ask questions if you do not understand or like the answers. You are making the exact same mistakes that we told you not to make.

Binary serialization is quite tricky and I advice you NOT to try doing that by yourself.  reinterpret_cast on a piece of memory is NOT going to give you a valid object (unless the object is trivially constructible and trivially copyable). And your endianess, padding, alignment and size of objects will make your file format heavily dependent on compiler settings, compilers used and the architecture of your system. So either serialize your data in a text format (e.g. json) OR use an existing serialization library like protobuf (from google) or flatbuffers

TLDR : do NOT try to read/write binary data yourself! And with 2 million players, using a file is definitely the wron approach anyway. Any modification will force you to write the whole file again! (totally nullifying any performance you might have gained by going binary). As said you probably need a database.

Strings and text are known as variable length records.  The common methods to handle variable length records are 1) Write the length first, then the content; 2) Write the content ending with a terminating char (like '\0').  The first method allows you to read the quantity, allocate memory of that size, then block read the text.  With the 2nd, you have to read one character at a time until the terminating char is found; reallocating your memory as necessary.

Don't binary write pointers or objects with pointers e.g. std::vector, std::string.  The operating system may not load your executable in the same place or give you memory in the same place as the pointer stored in the file.  Write the content of the target of the pointer.    The class should be in charge of writing its members to the file; as the class knows the details of the members.
